# Angular 4: Ng2SearchPipeModule using this module for the search. Not working properly on the Data in Numeric

Tags: javascript, angular

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IFavContactSchema } from './favSchema';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FavContactServiceService {
  allContactDetails:IFavContactSchema[] = [
    {
      first_name:"neha",middle_name:"singh",last_name:"sengar",email:"neha.singh931126@gmail.com",mobile_number:9898989898,phone_number:8989898989,notes:"Add to my faver",calling_rate:"frequent"
    },
    {
      first_name:"sonal",last_name:"trivedi",email:"sonal.trivedi@gmail.com",mobile_number:9092312345,phone_number:8989898989,notes:"Add to my onme",calling_rate:"frequent"
    },
    {
      first_name:"oshin",last_name:"sharma",email:"oshin.sharma@gmail.com",mobile_number:9522335434,phone_number:8989898989,notes:"Add to my tow",calling_rate:"frequent"
    },
    {
      first_name:"karasadn",last_name:"sdasd",email:"karan.veer@gmail.com",mobile_number:8839367967,phone_number:8989898989,notes:"Add to my three",calling_rate:"non_frequent"
    },
    {
      first_name:"kunil",last_name:"sharma",email:"kanul.sharma@gmail.com",mobile_number:9097854322,phone_number:8989898989,notes:"Add to my four",calling_rate:"frequent"
    },
    {
      first_name:"kane",last_name:"jain",email:"ranie.jain@gmail.com",mobile_number:8989673422,phone_number:8989898989,notes:"Add to my five",calling_rate:"frequent"
    },
    {
      first_name:"sane",last_name:"sharma",email:"punit.deer@gmail.com",mobile_number:9000000000,phone_number:8989898989,notes:"Add to my six",calling_rate:"non_frequent"
    },
  ];
  constructor() { }

  addContacts(details:IFavContactSchema){
      this.allContactDetails.push(details);
      return "Data Added Successfully";
  }
  
  getAllContacts(){
      return this.allContactDetails;
  }
  
  deleteContact(i){
    this.allContactDetails.splice(i, 1);
  }

  getContact(i){
    return this.allContactDetails[i];
  }

  updateContact(i,updatedContact){
    this.allContactDetails[i] = updatedContact;
  }
}
```

```js
TS
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IFavContactSchema } from '../favSchema';
import { FavContactServiceService } from '../fav-contact-service.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-favourites-list',
  templateUrl: './favourites-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./favourites-list.component.css']
})
export class FavouritesListComponent implements OnInit {
  key: string = 'first_name'; //set default
  reverse: boolean = false;
  p: number = 1;
  favContactLists:IFavContactSchema[];
  constructor(private favConService:FavContactServiceService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.favContactLists = this.favConService.getAllContacts();

  }
  deleteContact(i:Number){
    this.favConService.deleteContact(i);
  }
  sort(key){
    this.key = key;
    this.reverse = !this.reverse;
  }
}
```

```html
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Fav Contacts</h2>
  <nav class="navbar">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="filter">      
  </nav>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th (click)="sort('first_name')">Name
            <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" *ngIf="key =='name'" [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
        </th>
        <th (click)="sort('email')">Email</th>
        <th (click)="sort('calling_rate')">Calling Rate</th>
        <th (click)="sort('mobile_number')">Mobile Number</th>
        <th>Actions</th> 
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngIf="favContactLists?.length > 0; else no_record">
      <tr *ngFor="let contact of favContactLists| filter:filter | orderBy: key : reverse| paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p };let i=index">
        <td>{{ i+1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ contact.first_name  + " " }}{{contact.middle_name ? contact.middle_name : ""}}{{ " " + contact.last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ contact.email }}</td>
        <td *ngIf="contact.calling_rate == 'frequent'; else non_frequent" >{{ "Frequent" }}</td>
        <ng-template #non_frequent><td>{{ "Non Frequent" }}</td></ng-template>
        <td >{{ contact.mobile_number }}</td>
        <td><a [routerLink]="['/edit', i+1]">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
            </a>
            <a (click) = "deleteContact(i)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </a>
        </td>
       </tr>
      
    </tbody>
    <ng-template #no_record>
      <tbody>
        <td colspan="5" class="active cen" align="center">No Record Found</td>
      </tbody>
    </ng-template>
    <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am new to Angular facing a small issue.
Using the Ng2SearchPipeModule for the search It is working fine for the Data in string but not with the data in Number. I am attaching the Screenshot below...

For some search scenario working fine but for some not.
Please Help.

There are two images one with the normal search and one in which all the records are there even if it doesnot match the filtering criteria

Comment: You can provide piece of code for better understanding.

Comment: I have attached the snippet. The search doesnot work with the full name and Number properly. please help

Comment: A plunkr would do you better